# Arquivo anexo de email com file upload no django

Tags: django

Preciso enviar um arquivo do request.FILES de um campo File como anexo no e-mail. Estou seguindo topicos que ensinam isso, mas nao está dando certo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Django do meu projeto é 1.5

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
def send_templated_email(subject, email_template_name, email_context, recipients, 
                    sender=None, bcc=None, reply_to=None, fail_silently=True, files=None):

from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

c = Context(email_context)
if not sender:
    sender = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

template = loader.get_template(email_template_name)

text_part = strip_tags(template.render(c))
html_part = template.render(c)

if reply_to:
    headers = {'Reply-To': reply_to}
else:
    headers = {}

if type(recipients) == str:
    if recipients.find(','):
        recipients = recipients.split(',')
elif type(recipients) != list:
    recipients = [recipients,]

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                            text_part,
                            sender,
                            recipients,
                            bcc=bcc,
                            headers=headers)
# if files:
#     if type(files) != list:
#         files = [files,]

#     for f in files:
#         msg.attach_file(f)

if files:
    msg.attach(files.name, files.read(), files.content_type)

msg.attach_alternative(html_part, "text/html")

return msg.send(fail_silently)
```

Na pratica a parte do anexo é esta que vou destacar:

```
msg.attach(files.name, files.read(), files.content_type)
```

Sendo que em files eu estou passando **request.FILES['anexo']**

O email é enviado com sucesso, porém no lugar do corpo aparece o read do arquivo:

```
JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9MKOCAwIG9iago8PAovRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQovTiAzCi9BbHRlcm5hdGUgL0RldmljZVJHQgovTGVuZ3RoIDI1OTMKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnicnZZ3VFTXFofPvXd6oc0w dBh6r1IGEOkdpFdRGGYGG....
```

Já tentei também com o attach_file, mas o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `files`? Um objeto só ou uma lista/dict?

Comment: Eu tentei das duas formas. Mas isso é muito antigo, eu nem lembro mais como resolvi...postei em janeiro